# Cassandra write how to check what is written

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I have Datastax cassandra multi-node cluster. I have only 2 bulk load process which happens on specific interval, however I can see from Opscenter URL write happening for all nodes every 5 mins. How can I check what gets written to this often is there a way. I tried to check the Write for CFs but that was not helpful.

please let me know is there a way to find out what is getting written in cassandra?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

OpsCenter collects metrics from the cluster and stores them in it's own CF named "OpsCenter".  Data collection happens on a regular basis... most likely this is the activity you are seeing.